# What am I doing wrong with this simple problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When solving for A you can do the simple way of multiplying Z and dividing X+Y.

$$A*{X+Y\over Z}=W$$
$$A={WZ\over X+Y}$$

Or the way no one would ever do...
$$A*{X+Y\over Z}=W$$
$$A*\left({X\over Z}+ {Y\over Z}\right)=W$$
$$A ={W\over \left({X\over Z}+ {Y\over Z}\right)}$$
This appears to me to be equal to.
$$A ={W* \left({Z\over X}+ {Z\over Y}\right)}$$

Clearly this can not be true. Could someone point me to the rule that I am simply forgetting?

Comment: $1/(X/Z + Y/Z)$ is not $(Z/X +Z/Y)$

Comment: ${W\over{X\over Z}+{Y\over Z}}\times{Z\over Z}= {W\times Z\over{X\over Z}\times Z+{Y\over Z}\times Z} = {WZ\over X+Y}$

Comment: The last line is wrong. Take $W=1,X=1,Y=1,Z=2$ for example: $\displaystyle\frac{W}{\frac{X}{Z}+\frac{Y}{Z}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}=1$, but $\displaystyle{W}\cdot(\frac{Z}{X}+\frac{Z}{Y})=1\cdot(\frac{2}{1}+\frac{2}{1})=4$.

Comment: In words, the reciprocal of the sum is not equal to the sum of the reciprocals.  A common error is to mistakenly assume that the blip of the blop is equal to the blop of the blip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error here is that while it's true that

$$A = W \cdot \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{X}{Z}+\dfrac{Y}{Z}}$$

Your next assumption is false as pointed out by Stefan Hansen in comments.

$$\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{X}{Z}+\dfrac{Y}{Z}} \ne \dfrac{Z}{X} + \dfrac{Z}{Y}$$

To see this let $X = 1$, $Y = 2$ and $Z = 3$

$$\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{X}{Z}+\dfrac{Y}{Z}} = \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{2}{3}} = 1 \ne \dfrac{Z}{X} + \dfrac{Z}{Y} = \dfrac{3}{1} + \dfrac{3}{2} = 4.5$$